# How to change HTML datepicker format

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to change html date format to `mm-dd-yyyy` from default HTML date format`(dd-mm-yyyy)`.

Anyone help me to achieve this.

**Note: I want achieve without adding jquery library files.**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
  <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What datepicker library are you using?

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat (maybe)

Comment: Apologies for the latest update.!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a syntax error:

```
$("#birthday").datepicker({
  "dateFormat" : "mm-dd-yyyy" 
});
```

Comment: Not helpful....

Comment: I updated the runtime of your snippet and now that you corrected it, it works as you wished it to work. So I'm confused why you say it wasn't helpful

Comment: the format you did its a correction of my code. But I don't want to use any libraries

Comment: you didn't say that  in your question when I could read it. So you changed it. By the way now your question became how to do a datepicker without using a library. Good luck with that because it's impossible unless you write your own.

Comment: Yes it was my mistake only. I just updated my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have `SyntaxError: unexpected token: '{'"` and Double Quote would not be used for `"dateFormat"`, It should be `dateFormat`

Please correct Syntex in

**Wrong** [Used in your code]

```
   $("#birthday").datepicker() {
  "dateFormat" : "mm-dd-yyyy" 
});
```

**Right**

```
  $( "#birthday" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
    });
```

**Example**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
    })
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Placeholder should display as mm-dd-yyyy. This one also not helpful.

Comment: I am adding a placeholder too. But your issue was not about placeholder

Comment: Is there any possible to do without adding library?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a syntax error as others are posting here.
I used the same syntax you had in your code and it works like a charm. I think you were missing probably a library.

By adding these two libraries

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>`
```

and

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

it works fine.

```js
$("#birthday").datepicker({
  "dateFormat" : "mm-dd-yyyy" 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
  <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It will not helpful. Pls check your the format.

Comment: yes it was a syntax error before it was corrected after watching my answer.. and now the snippet works having the right placeholder and formatting the picked date as mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: There are two datepicker in your answer. and also the format wrong.